# Matching words starting with characters before digits

Tags: java

I have an array of files name like this : `aaa123129ppp.txt` , `cpo123129LLL.txt`, `jak0000011-oo.txt`

I want the first characters before the digits results like this `aaa` , `cpo`, `jak`

```
    for(int i = 0; i <fileName.length ;i++)
    {
       String name = name[i].replaceAll("\\d", "");            
    }
```

the above will remove only digits

Comment: you can match the first result of `[a-z]+`

Comment: you want start char or first char after digit??

Comment: @khelwood i fixed it thanks.

Comment: @mjsoft first characters after digit

Comment: Just use: `name[i].replaceAll("\\d.*". "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated version:

`\\d.+`

The regex matches whatever comes after the numbers as well as including them.

This creates the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i <fileName.length ;i++)
{
   String name = name[i].replaceAll("\\d.+", "");            
}
```

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/1J2U3m/6)

Comment: I dont want the end of `.` with the above replaceall ill have `aaa.txt` i want only `aaa` is that possible ?